iterate over groups with `group_walk` in original order
Using dplyr::group_walk, I would like to iterate on the original order of the dataframe.
For example:
library(dplyr)
tibble(
  group = c("C", "B", "A"),
  values = c(1, 2, 3)
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_walk(~ print(.x))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   values
#>    <dbl>
#> 1      3
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   values
#>    <dbl>
#> 1      2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   values
#>    <dbl>
#> 1      1

I would like to iterate in order "1, 2, 3".
Is there a way of iterating with group_walk over the original order of the dataframe? Or will it always iterate using the group order?

See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455233/how-to-prevent-autosort-by-group-split-and-preserve-original-order

For your data it should look like tibble(group = factor(c("C", "B", "A"), levels=c("C", "B", "A")), values = c(1, 2, 3)) %>% group_by(group) %>% group_walk(~ print(.x))

library(tidyverse)
tibble(
  group = c("C", "B", "A"),
  values = c(1, 2, 3)
) %>%
  mutate(group = fct_inorder(group)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_walk(~ print(.x))

Thanks to @andre-wildberg
